¿Como actualizar los datos en Angular?
Estoy consumiendo un endpoint para actualizar un registro, la cuestión es que no me lo actualiza porque el id viene indefinido, y es ahí el tema... que no hallo por que... tengo poca experiencia en angular y se que este tema es fácil para muchos... adjunto mis códigos para el contexto.
Servicio:
  updateCobrador(idCobrador: number, cobradorData: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log(cobradorData);
    return this.http.put<any>(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/cobrador/${idCobrador}`,
      cobradorData,
    );
  }

Componente:
updateCobrador(updatedCobradorData: any) {
    const idCobrador = updatedCobradorData.idCobrador; // Obtener el ID del cobrador del formulario
    const updatedCobrador = {
      idCobrador: idCobrador, // Asignar el ID correctamente
      nombre: updatedCobradorData.nombre,
      horaInicial: updatedCobradorData.horaInicial,
      horaFinal: updatedCobradorData.horaFinal,
      estatus: updatedCobradorData.estatus,
    };

    this.cobradoresServices
      .updateCobrador(idCobrador, updatedCobrador)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.getCobradores();
      });
}

HTML:
<form #cobradorForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateCobrador(cobradorForm.value)">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="IdCobrador"
      name="idCobrador"
      [(ngModel)]="cobradorSeleccionado.idCobrador"
      required /></mat-form-field
  ><mat-form-field
    ><input
      matInput
      placeholder="Nombre"
      name="nombre"
      [(ngModel)]="cobradorSeleccionado.nombre"
      required /></mat-form-field
  ><mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      type="text"
      placeholder="Hora Inicial (HH:mm:ss)"
      name="horaInicial"
      [(ngModel)]="cobradorSeleccionado.horaInicial"
      required /></mat-form-field
  ><mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      type="text"
      placeholder="Hora Final (HH:mm:ss)"
      name="horaFinal"
      [(ngModel)]="cobradorSeleccionado.horaFinal"
      required /></mat-form-field
  ><mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Estatus</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      placeholder="Estatus"
      name="estatus"
      [(ngModel)]="cobradorSeleccionado.estatus"
      required
    >
      <mat-option value="Activo">Activo</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</mat-option>
    </mat-select></mat-form-field
  ><button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
    Actualizar Cobrador
  </button>
</form>

En Postman seria URL: http://localhost:8080/api/cobrador/21
{
    "nombre": "domiciliacion22",
    "horaInicial": "04:00:00",
    "horaFinal": "20:00:00",
    "estatus": "Activo"
}

Pero la respuesta que me da el navegador es:
{ idCobrador: undefined, nombre: 'domiciliacion22', horaInicial: '04:00:00', horaFinal: '20:00:00', estatus: 'Inactivo' } estatus: "Inactivo" horaFinal: "20:00:00" horaInicial: "04:00:00" idCobrador: undefined nombre: "domiciliacion22"}

PUT http://localhost:8080/api/cobrador/undefined 400 (Bad Request)
cobradores.component.ts:63 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/cobrador/undefined', ok: false, …}


Si llega tu ID al backend? Por otro lado, si usas any automáticamente suceden 2 cosas: 1. Te complicas la vida porque no sabes que estas usando. 2. Dejas sin razón de ser a TypeScript, ya que esa es una de sus principales funciones, el checado de tipos. Puedes usar Quicktype para copiar y pegar respuestas JSON y generar tu interface.

Por otro lado, que versión de Angular es esta? Usualmente declararías el form en TypeScript. Por otro lado no esta claro porque tienes un input para el ID, no deberías tener un select para así seleccionar IDs existendes? si no, cómo sabrías que el ID que tienes va a actualizar lo que quieres?

ya intentaste ponerle (ngSubmit)="updateCobrador(cobradorForm.idCobrador)?
